# Upgrading a CiviCRM System

Tags: upgrade

We have a CiviCRM system that hasn't been updated for 5 years and the guy who used to do this has left.  Now I do have a lot of IT knowledge but am lost with this.  Please, can someone advise how much of an easy task this is and if not anyone who can do it for us?

Thank you :)

Comment: What is the version of CiviCRM? It should say in the footer when you are logged in. Is it hosted on a virtual machine where you can easily take a snapshot? This would be the easiest so that you could quickly attempt upgrades and then restore if it fails/breaks.

Comment: The first thing I would figure out is which tables in the database are storing data for your installation. Also determine where the files are located on the server. Is Civi being hosted on Drupal, WordPress, or Joomla?

Comment: perhaps also worth checking that if civicrm hasn't been upgraded, has your cms been upgraded? both carry security risks if upgrading is not happening

Comment: Also consider: whether your underlying PHP and MySQL are too old, and whether you have any custom modules specific to your organisation that may need development work.

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading is not exactly simple, but it can be done with a lot of IT knowledge. You can find information about the upgrade at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/ .

If you need an expert to help you search in the partner list: https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors .